# gfortran matmul openMP

Tags: openmp, matrix-multiplication, gfortran

Does gfortran (gcc-9) automatically parallelize the `matmul()` intrinsic function if compiled with `-fopenmp` (and run whith `OMP_NUM_THREADS` > 1 in Linux)? If so, is there a way to turn it off?

There is no `-fextrnal-blas` flag applied to call a parallel BLAS for the `matmul`s.

Comment: It would be very strange if it did. Do you have any reason to think it may in fact be the case?

Comment: Some routines with no openMP statements but with `matmul()`s and (`reshape()`s) gets different timings from `system_clock()` and `cpu_time()` when OMP_NUM_THREADS is bigger than 1 (with `-fopenmp`).

Comment: However today I noticed that on the desktop they match for any number of threads... On the laptop only for one thread. Very odd, but may be due to hyperthreading overhead or something like that.

Comment: @VladimirF Or runtime environment/libraries? The hardware is quite different but both run the same OS, the same compiler and the same code (if I'm not doing something really stupid, but git helps with that).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily see for yourself in the code of GCC:

https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libgfortran/generated/matmul_r4.c

Many Fortran intrinsic calls are actually implemented as external functions provided by the library *libgfortran*, and `matmul` is not an exception. There is a separate C code of `matmul` for all basic numerical types (and their kinds), and also alternative forms for various target vector instructions sets (AVX, FMA, etc). But none of them apparently uses any OpenMP directives.

Comment: Thank you, I really like this answer, have never looked the GCC source before.

Comment: As a side note, it is a little funny that there are 3000 lines of AVX-adapted code while in my experience a triple do-loop with some optimization is usually faster.